# Difference between lambda and -> operator in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lambda

The following two scopes generate the same result, which syntax is preferable and is there any other difference?

```
scope :paid, lambda { |state| where(state: state) }

scope :paid, ->(state) { where(state: state) }
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's preferable, due to readibility reasons, to use new syntax `->` (introduced in Ruby 1.9) for single-line blocks and `lambda` for multi-line blocks. Example:

```
# single-line
l = ->(a, b) { a + b }
l.call(1, 2)

# multi-line
l = lambda do |a, b|
  tmp = a * 3
  tmp * b / 2
end
l.call(1, 2)
```

It seems a community convention established in [bbatsov/ruby-style-guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#lambda-multi-line).

So, in your case, would be better:

```
scope :paid, ->(state) { where(state: state) }
```

Answer (score 4):

`->` is literal syntax, like `"`. Its meaning is fixed by the language specification.

`Kernel#lambda` is a method just like any other method. It can be overridden, removed, overwritten, monkeypatched, intercepted, …

So, semantically, they are very different.

It is also possible that their performance is different. `Kernel#lambda` will *at least* have the overhead of a method call. The fact that the execution engine cannot actually know what `Kernel#lambda` does at runtime (since it could be monkeypatched) would also preclude any static optimizations, although I don't believe any existing Ruby execution engine statically optimizes lambda literals in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference, both returns the same `Proc` object:

```
irb(main):033:0> lambda {|x| x*x}
=> #<Proc:0x007ff525b55b90@(irb):33 (lambda)>
irb(main):034:0> ->(x) {x*x}
=> #<Proc:0x007ff525b7e068@(irb):34 (lambda)>
```

In my opinion, `->` is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

markets answer is the correct answer. One quick addition though - if a multi-line lambda is ever needed as an arugment, there are 2 approaches that work. For example creating a scope in a model, you may want to consider this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Bad - this will error because we are passing a block as an argument in
  # a method without parenthesis
  scope cool_users lambda do |arg|
    # some long query
  end

  # OK - when parenthesis are added, the lambda block will work 
  # without error (and passes rubocop). However, using parenthesis 
  # around a lambda block looks weird IMO
  scope(cool_users lambda do |arg|
    # some long query
  end)

  # Good - replacing do / end with {} functions without error, passes 
  # rubocop and looks good IMO
  scope cool_users lambda { |arg|
    # some long query
  }
end
```