# Meaning of `->()` syntax in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is exactly the meaning of this Ruby on Rails Syntax

`options = ->(p) {{controller: 'clients', subdomain: "m.#{Rails.env}"}.merge!(p)}`

I have never encountered this syntax before: `->(p)`.

I could not even find resources on that on google. Does anyone have a tutorial about that?

Comment: If you'd like to delve more deeply into Ruby lambdas, I have a conference presentation about them posted on YouTube at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hyRgf6Qc5pw; slide show is at https://speakerdeck.com/keithrbennett/ruby-lambdas-functional-conf-bangalore-oct-2014.

Comment: This SO thread could be interesting for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28215281/3033649

Comment: You have a smorgasbord of choices for calling `options`: `options.call(p)`, `options[p]`, `options.yield(p)`, `options===p` and the still-supported-but-on-its-way-out `options.(p)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is just additional lambda syntax (since Ruby version 1.9). Old syntax:

```
options = lambda { |p| { controller: 'clients', subdomain: "m.#{Rails.env}"}.merge!(p)}
```

Comment: Now called "stabby lambda".

Comment: "New" is relative. I personally remember it existing in 2007, might have been even earlier than that.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, you are right, Ruby 1.9 released in 2007, but previous versions had not this syntax.