# Difference between `->` and `lambda` in ruby

Tags: ruby, lambda

What is the difference between `->` and `lambda`? Example:

```
scope :test, lambda {where(:name => "test")}
```

versus

```
scope :test, -> {where(:name => "test")}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28215047/difference-between-lambda-and-operator-in-ruby

Comment: So it seems the second one is better.

Comment: Could you please put the question @joshua.paling has addressed to as the question that my question is duplicate of, I guess its more like my question...