# how to create Proc to prevent DRY in rails model? Rails 5.2.1, rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, proc

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :projects
  validates :name, presence: true

  validates :phone,
    presence: {
      message: "Phone or Email can not be blank",
      if: Proc.new { |a| a.email.blank? }
    },
    length: {
      minimum: 10,
      unless: Proc.new { |a| a.phone.blank? }
    }

  validates :email,
    uniqueness: {
      unless: Proc.new { |a| a.email.blank? }
    },
    presence: {
      message: "Phone/Email can't both be blank",
      if: Proc.new { |a| a.phone.blank? }
    },
    format: {
      with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP,
      unless: Proc.new { |a| a.email.blank? }
    }

    def phone_blank?
      Proc.new { |a| a.phone.blank? }
    end
end
```

How do I create a method to replace with all the Proc?
I just learned about Proc and I'm not too familiar with that yet.  I tried to use :phone_blank to replace all the proc after if:/unless:, but it failed to work.  Can someone tell me how to make the phone_blank? method work to replace all the proc embeded in the code?  thanks~

**edited:**
I forgot to mention I'm using rails_admin for the admin interface.  If I call methods in if:/unless:, the admin panel will show **Model 'Client' could not be found** then the model would disappear from the admin panel.  I'm not sure it's a rails_admin thing or that's how Rails 5 behaves.  I'm quite new to RoR and still quite confuse with all different versions of Rails....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using method there is no need in `Proc` wrapper.

e.g.

```ruby
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :projects
  validates :name, presence: true

  validates :phone,
    presence: {
      message: "Phone or Email can not be blank",
      if: email_blank?
    },
    length: {
      minimum: 10,
      unless: phone_blank?
    }

  validates :email,
    uniqueness: {
      unless: email_blank?
    },
    presence: {
      message: "Phone/Email can't both be blank",
      if: phone_blank?
    },
    format: {
      with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP,
      unless: email_blank?
    }

  def phone_blank?
    phone.blank?
  end

  def email_blank?
    email.blank?
  end
end
```

---

<s>Also you can simply specify this condition in validation directly without method or `Proc` as a string.</s>

e.g.

```ruby
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :projects
  validates :name, presence: true

  validates :phone,
    presence: {
      message: "Phone or Email can not be blank",
      if: 'email.blank?'
    },
    length: {
      minimum: 10,
      if: 'phone.present?'
    }

  validates :email,
    uniqueness: {
      if: 'email.present?'
    },
    presence: {
      message: "Phone/Email can't both be blank",
      if: 'phone.blank?'
    },
    format: {
      with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP,
      if: 'email.present?'
    }
end
```

Comment: Are you sure about the `if: 'email.blank?'` things?

Comment: rails ~5 doesn't take string for if: and unless: I think.

Comment: I've tried this way but it doens't work in Rails 5.2.1 I think.  I'm using rails_admin for the admin interface.  The client panel would dissapear when I declare a method then call the method in if:/unless:.  I don't know if it's a rails_admin thing or that's how Rails 5 works

Comment: Yup, correct, rails >5 doesn't accept strings for conditional validations.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a class method that returns a lambda, something like:

```
def self.blank_field?(field)
  ->(m) { m.send(field).blank? }
end
```

and then say things like:

```
validates :phone,
  presence: {
    message: "Phone or Email can not be blank",
    if: blank_field?(:email)
  },
  length: {
    minimum: 10,
    unless: blank_field?(:phone)
  }
```

Note that we use `blank_field?` instead of `blank?` since `blank?` is already taken and we don't want to override it. And since this is an "internal" method, we don't have to worry about `public_send` versus `send`.

Comment: I'd suggest to replace `send` with `[]` to read attribute on a model. e.g. `m[field].blank?`

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm using rails_admin.  I'm starting to suspect that because of rails_admin, the solutions you mention cease to work.  I really don't know.  too noob....  thanks for the solution though.  I will go dig more about lambda

Comment: sfate, my code would throw an error when I replace send with []

Comment: @sfate But using `#[]` will bypass an accessor method (if you have one) and that can lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: @MorboRe' Are you getting a NameError in the console or the logs? Have you defined `blank_field?` before you try to use it?

Comment: @MorboRe' agree, but it's not safe to use just `#send`, at least it should be `public_send` and probably check on `#respond_to?` as well.

Comment: @sfate Public/private is irrelevant in this context so there's no need to bother with `public_send`. There's no much point to checking `#respond_to?` either, your test suite should pick up any typos.

Comment: ＠mu is too short, got an error from rails_admin, I think all the problems are caused by rails_admin not accepting certain format of code.  Maybe I should just drop rails_admin and get better with Rails before move on the any plug-in of it.

Comment: But is there anything in the error logs? Have you tried to run the code from the Rails console?

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but an alternative approach in DRY-ing things is to make use of [`with_options`](https://apidock.com/rails/Object/with_options):

```
with_options if: -> { email.blank? } do
  validates :phone, presence: { message: "Phone or Email can not be blank" }
end

with_options if: -> { phone.blank? } do
  validates :email, presence: { message: "Phone/Email can't both be blank" }
end

with_options if: -> { email.present? } do
  validates :phone, length: { minimum: 10 }
  validates :email, uniqueness: true, format: { with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP }
end
```

*This is especially useful when the validations have conditions depending on different... say, categories (if you have a `category` column), and you can just simply group these validations up `with_options`*

### Trivia:

You can think of `-> { ... }` just like `Proc.new { ... }` which you were already familiar with (though accurately speaking it's a `lambda` ... which is like a special type of `Proc`. If you're interested further, see these SO posts: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28215047/difference-between-lambda-and-operator-in-ruby) and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043181/ruby-lambda-vs-proc-new)